# Access denied error when trying to create database using phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql

A friend of mine asked me to help him with some minor php/mysql job. He gave me his cpanel access and I have to create a database for him.

I get the error:

```
MySQL issue : Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

When I type in phpMyAdmin:

```
CREATE DATABASE db_name;
```

Is there a way I can grant all priviledges to the user he provided, or is there a way I can create a database with other user?

Comment: Yo should have database wizard (where you can create db and add user)in cpanel, you don't have to do it manually?

Comment: you can see this as well: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/access-denied.html  You'll need ssh access to your hosting account

Comment: Possibly you must create the user and database using cPanel. PhpMyAdmin usually uses this information (privileges) to do this. Anyway, what problem happens?

Comment: @nevermind . Yes I know. When I click databases, it should appear a field where I can type the database name. Unfortunately for me this input does not show up.

Comment: Are there databases already, is there some db creation limit? Easiest way - contact hosting support. :)

Comment: There are no database, just the information_schema

Answer (score -1):

You can grant usage by using

```
 grant usage on *.* to prasad@localhost identified by 'passwd';
```

Another thing regarding access denied to even `localhost` is caused when your firewall is active. You can try disabling antivirus software and also firewall.

A suggestion will be if you are using mysql, then mysql workbench is a great to have. You can create databases through GUI quite easily

Comment: When I type the command I get the same error like before : Access denied